# Conditional Logic in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm doing an assignment for a stats class, and I'm new to programming.  I don't want to ask a stupid question, but I've searched and can't find an answer.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

double pareto(double x, double alpha, double beta)  
{
    double val = beta * pow(alpha, beta) / pow(x, beta+1);

    if( alpha <= 0 ) printf("error");
    else if( beta <= 0 ) printf("error");
    else if( alpha >= x) return(0);
    else return(val);
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    double alpha;
    double beta;
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    scanf("%lf", &alpha);
    scanf("%lf", &beta);
    printf("%f\n", pareto(x,alpha,beta));
    return 0;
}
```

When I test the code as follows:

```
echo 3 -2 1 | ./paretodens
```

I get the output:

```
error0.000000
```

I would like it to be simply "error".  I hope my question makes sense.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your program die if there's an error:

```
if (alpha <= 0)
{ 
    printf("error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

That way the function will never return and you don't call the final print statement at all.

Otherwise note that `pareto` has no method for signaling an error to the caller! If you wanted to con­tin­ue execution after an error, you would have to redesign your function to allow for an error state to hap­pen and to be communicated.

---

Since you're new: also note that your code can be made a lot shorter, since you don't need an `else` after a `return` or `exit`:

```
double pareto(double x, double alpha, double beta)
{
    if (alpha <= 0 || beta <= 0) { printf("Error\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    return alpha >= 0 ? 0 : beta * pow(alpha, beta) / pow(x, beta + 1);
}
```

And notice that you don't need to perform the computation unless you know that you need it!

Comment: If it's an error, you should probably pass something other than `0` to `exit()`.

Comment: Just an idea: if this is performance-critical, profile also the alternative `beta/x * pow(alpha/x, beta)`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, and taught me quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is always getting executed:

```
printf("%f\n", pareto(x,alpha,beta));
```

You don't have a condition at all for that. Also, your pareto() function will sometimes return no specified value. You should fix that and make it always return some specific value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print either 'error' or the correct return value from the function, but not both. The problem is that you call the `pareto` function from inside a call to `printf`. The `pareto` function itself has a call to printf, that's why your code prints both 'error' and the return value.

Personally, I would clean it up as follows:

```
double pareto(double x, double alpha, double beta)  
{
    if (alpha <= 0 || beta <= 0)
        return -1;

    if (alpha >= x)
        return 0;

    return beta*pow(alpha,beta)/pow(x,beta+1);
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    double alpha;
    double beta;
    double val;

    scanf("%lf", &x);
    scanf("%lf", &alpha);
    scanf("%lf", &beta);

    val = pareto(x,alpha,beta);

    if (val < 0)
        printf("error");
    else
        printf("%f\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```